# Insertion into a binary heap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tree, heap

If I have an  array representing a minimum binary heap that contains the values {2, 8, 3, 10, 16, 7, 18, 13, 15}, what would the array look like after inserting the value of 4? Also, how would I demonstrate this to be correct?

I deduced it would be 2,4,3,10,8,7,18,13,15,16. Is that correct?

Comment: verify it using http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Heap.html and http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/visualization/heap.html

Comment: Can you show the steps you followed to get to your result? It's rather difficult to know what level of understanding you're at (so we don't have to explain everything from scratch) and what you did wrong (if anything) if you just post the answer without any explanation of how you got there. I also personally don't find "Is my work correct" questions particularly useful - if it's homework, just hand it in or ask your teacher for help.

Comment: http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/29/a-better-way-to-do-it-the-heap/

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate that your min heap is correct, you need to prove recursively that your child nodes are larger than your root node

If your root node is n, your child nodes are 2n+1 and 2n+2, so iterate through your tree and check if child nodes are greater than parent. If this logic is not satisfied anywhere then your heap is bad.

```
                     2
                  8     3
               10   16 7  18
             13  15
```

push at end

```
                     2
                  8     3
               10   **16** 7  18
            13  15  4
```

compare and replace with parent

```
                     2
                  **8**     3
               10   4 7  18
            13  15  16
```

compare and replace with parent-no replacement

```
                     **2**
                  4     3
               10   8 7  18
            13  15  16
```